# How to config subdomain in nginx to point to specefic html file in same tomcat host

Tags: tomcat, nginx

I have a site on tomcat like www.mysite.com:2121 and nginx point (as proxy) like this:

> mysite.com => www.mysite.com:2121
>
> www.mysite.com => www.mysite.com:2121

I want to creat a sub domain like ui.mysite.com to point to mysite.com:8080/index_ui.html like this:

> ui.mysite.com => mysite.com:8080/index_ui.html

i try this in nginx.conf:

```
  server {
    listen          80;
    server_name     mysite.com www.mysite.com; 

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass htt://www.mysite.com:2121;
    }
  }
server {
    listen          80;
    server_name     ui.mysite.com ; 
    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass htt://www.mysite.com:2121/index_ui.html;
    }
  }
```

this code work only for HTML and not work for CSS and JS because these files is in same host and browser looks for them in

> ui.mysite.com/css (NOK)

instead of

> mysite.com/css (OK)

i use this config too that means redirect all exept index_ui.html:

> ```
> rewrite ^(?!^(/index_ui.html)$)/.*$htt://www.xrdini.com/$1 permanent;
> ```

This work better, But in not good because it is not good for SEO and it make redirect user to 
mysite.com/index_ui.html 
Not 
ui.mysite.com/index_ui.html

How to config Nginx And/Or Tomcat ?

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting the default rule to only server index_ui.html, you'll need to set a specific rule for the root directory and use the default rule to reverse proxy as normal:

```
server {
    listen          80;
    server_name     ui.mysite.com ;

    # Location block for specifically URL /
    location = / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass htt://www.mysite.com:2121/index_ui.html;
    }
    # Location block for all other URLs
    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass htt://www.mysite.com:2121;
    }
}
```

Comment: No,It not work completely. What about CSS an JS imported in index_ui.html? Also other request (for example /Server?do=Content&id=10) direct to ui.mysite.com/Server?do=content&id=10 that witch is in www.mysite.com/Server?Content&id=10